Helm chart project deployment with multiple charts
I have a project, and need to deploy it (using harness). the structrue of the project is exactly like that, with 13 modules
Root
  - Module1
     templates
     chart.yaml  
     values.yaml

  - Module2
     templates
     chart.yaml
     values.yaml

  - Module3
     templates
     chart.yaml
     values.yaml


pipeline.yaml

I have configure the project like that, in the pipeline.yaml file:
    version: v1
tasks:
  - ref: helm-chart-publish
    params:
      - name: chart-path
        value: /
        
  - ref: helm-chart-publish
    params:
      - name: chart-path
        value: /

  - ref: helm-chart-publish
    params:
      - name: chart-path
        value: / 

 

But in harness deployment get error of:
Dry run manifest failed with error: error: no objects passed to apply
I think there is error in the pipeline configuration, but didn't succeseed to figure it out, can anyone help with this issue. thanks

You tagged this question with [tag:helmfile]; are you actually using Helmfile as part of this setup ("launch 13 parallel Helm charts" is in fact the thing it's good at)?
